# How to click on a cell to activate macro for adjacent cell

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to put together an Excel-based quick workflow management tool where my staff can click on a particular cell and the cell adjacent to it "clocks" in the current date.

The table looks something like:
`Name | Start Date | Completion Date | Click`

The `Start Date` will automatically populate based on cell value change under `Name` (which I've figured how how to make this happen), I want the `Completion Date` to then populate the current date against the relevant line that the staff has "clicked on" via hyperlink under `Click` as work may not be completed in chronological order.

Is this a possibility that macro would be able to do without needing the staff to manually change the value of a particular cell in order to "clock on" the completion date?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a regular module:

```
Function SetDate() As Range
    'set the date one cell to the left
    Application.Caller.Offset(0, -1).Value = Now
    Set SetDate = Selection '<< need to return a range
End Function
```

Hyperlink formula:

```
=HYPERLINK("#SetDate()","<< Click to set date")
```

Comment: This is amazing! Thank you! :)