# VBA Need help identifying the active cell associated with macro enabled button

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a counter that displays how many times a macro enabled button is clicked.  I'm having trouble identifying the active cell associated with macro enabled button.  It will be anywhere from cell A9 through A50  (I will have multiple macro buttons that will apply on the page).
Code needs to look at cell directly to the right of the active cell and add 1 to that number when a button is pushed.  I'm new to VBA and not having success at applying the suggested questions to my scenario.

Here is how the button is being placed onto the sheet if it is helpful in resolving the problem.

```
Sub VBA_Input_Idea_inputbox()

  Dim MyInp As String
  Dim NextRow As Long
  Dim Counter As Long
  Dim btn As Button
  Dim t As Range


 Counter = Counter + 1

 MyInp = VBA.Interaction.InputBox("Please input idea", "LEARNING REQUEST")
   If MyInp = "" Then Exit Sub
 NextRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).row + 1
 Range("C" & NextRow).Value = Excel.WorksheetFunction.Proper(MyInp)
 Set t = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & NextRow)
  Set btn = ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(t.Left, t.Top, t.Width, t.Height)
With btn
 .OnAction = "VBA_Love_It_msgbox3"
 .Caption = "Vote for this Idea!"
 .Name = "btn" & "Love This"
End With
  Range("B" & NextRow) = Counter

End Sub
```

Comment: `activecell.offset(,1)` ?

Comment: SJR- how would that look?  Iam getting an error when executing

    Sub Macro5()

        Cells(ActiveCell.Offset(, 1)).Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 + 1

        End Sub

Comment: I guess you would have to use `activecell.offset(,1).value=activecell.offset(,1).value+1` in the button click code. Not sure I follow what you're doing.

Comment: Sorry dont know how to format on this thread

Comment: Just store the cell address ***in*** the button.  `.ShapeRange.AlternativeText` seems like a good place to hide it.

Comment: SJR- your counter is working, but the cell the macro is sitting on is not becoming the "activecell"

Comment: All that code does is add 1 to the active cell. Which cell is active at the time is another matter. What do you mean by " the cell the macro is sitting on"? How does the active cell relate to the button?

Comment: If you mean the cell which is active when you create the button, use Comintern's suggestion.

Comment: In the macro attached to the button:  `ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell` will give you the cell under the button.   I know you just got your button-adding code all set, but you might find it easier to use hyperlinks for this:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54567563/how-to-click-on-a-cell-to-activate-macro-for-adjacent-cell/54568606#54568606   That approach get over the potential issue with buttons getting out of place and ending up affecting the wrong content.

Answer (score 0):

In the macro attached to the button, `Application.Caller` will give you the name of the button/shape calling the code:

```
Sub VBA_Love_It_msgbox3()
    With ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell.Offset(0, 1)
        .Value = .Value + 1
    End With
End Sub
```

EDIT: for this to work you need to ensure your buttons all have different names.

Comment: Yes, but how do I get it to adjust down the row?  Clicks on A9,A10,A11, etc are all entering onto the vote column on B9.

Comment: Tim Williams- I did add the code to give the code unique names, still had the issue.  I added a line ActiveWorkbook.Save after the procedure is run and that worked.  Thank you for your help!